# A condition for being a prime: $\;\forall m,n\in\mathbb Z^+\!:\,p=m+n\implies \gcd(m,n)=1$

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures

If $\;p=m+n$ where $p\in\mathbb P$, then $m,n$ are coprime, of course. But what about the converse?

Conjecture:

> $p$ is prime if $\;\forall m,n\in\mathbb Z^+\!:\,p=m+n\implies \gcd(m,n)=1$

Tested (and verified) for all $p<100000$.

Comment: This is very easy to prove

Comment: @EugenCovaci, yes I saw that. But I've never thought about this relationship before and I'm hunting for the 'Socratic' badge. $\;\overset{..}{\smile}$

Comment: There is no need to specify $p \ge 2$

Comment: You should work out a few examples by hand instead of 100,000 by computers.

Comment: @djechlin. Thanks for the tip, which is a good one. I'm working with my BigZ and the questions arise when examine this computer system.
https://forthmath.blogspot.se

Comment: The equivalence is not true in any UFD as written since e.g. $\, p = -p + 2p,\,$ and your positivity constraint cannot exclude that since UFDs generally are not ordered rings (e.g. $\,\Bbb Z[i] =\,$ Gaussian integers). It would be a good idea to remove that false statement.

Comment: @BillDubuque, thanks, I will!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is true. Suppose $p\geqslant 2$ is *not* prime. Then we can write $p=xy$ with $x,y\geqslant 2$. Then we find $p=m+n$, with $m=x$ and $n=x(y-1)$. Those are obviously not coprime.

Answer (score 10):

If $d \mid p$ and $d<p$, then $1 = \gcd(d, p-d) = \gcd(d, p) = d$, so $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 4):

for p = 1 obviously wrong
(for all positive integers m, n with m+n=p (of course there are no ones, doesn't matter) there is gcd(m,n)=1, but 1=p is not prime)

Comment: It's a bit terse and could be improved by a little more elaboration.  I think you are saying $p=1$ is not prime, but the condition on $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ holds vacuously.